# Team Foundation Server workspaces dissappear/missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have several projects mapped to a Workspace in TFS. I closed down my VS2010 window, did some other work, reopened it and all my workspaces were gone. I tried rebooting but they wouldn't come back. In my Windows Explorer the little green triangles next to the folders that my solutions were mapped to, were also gone.

Eventually I resigned myself to having somehow messed up the connection to the source control and tried to recreate the workspace I was using. It wouldn't however let me create the workspace as one of that name already existed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of googling, reboots and looking at silly things, I noticed Visual Studio seemed to think I was logged on as an alternate network account (one I had used earlier to access a shared network drive that the user I was logged onto my PC with didn't have access to)

I would have thought restarting the PC and logging on again would have resolved this, but it turned out I had clicked the "remember me" box. Even deleting the account from Control Panel -> User Accounts didn't help.

Eventually I came across [This site for removing saved network passwords](http://www.faqforge.com/windows/how-delete-saved-passwords-for-network-drives-in-windows/)

You just click, Start -> Run -> "Control Keymanager.dll"

This displays all the accounts you clicked "Remember me" for on network drives. You delete the one that's causing trouble (or all of them in my case), restart VS2010 and all your workspaces and project bindings are there again!

Comment: In Windows 7 you can also click Start and type "Manage Network Passwords" to access this.

Comment: @DanPuzey Ah, thanks for that. I'm still using WinXP here for the moment.

Comment: Had the same problem today. You sir, saved me alot of hours. Thank you :)

Comment: @Gunnar Awesome, that makes my writing it up worth while

Comment: In Windows 8, you must click Start and type "Manage Network Passwords" to access this

Comment: Great!  Really saved me some frustration!  This happened to me after a network account password change.

Comment: @cmartin wow, 8 years later.... glad it still helps

Comment: ... And 3 years later again after much frantic searching of the web! Thanks @MikeyMouse